# put text on the top of radio button

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I want to put text on the top of checkbox. Suppose to have this html code:

```
<div class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="pubblic" checked>Public
</div>
```

I want create a class css that dispose element in this way:

```
Public
  []
```

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flexbox can do that:

```css
.radio.col-up {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="radio col-up">
  <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="public" checked>Public
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position: absolute` , If you don't want to change your HTML part

```css
.radio {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.radio input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  margin: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="radio">
  <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="pubblic" checked>Public
</div>
```